# How to make map show to my current location automatically on opening my application?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, currentlocation

I am developing an application in which I am using maps. I want that as soon a I open my application it should automatically zoom in to show my location on map, but currently what is happening is that map is visible but current location is not shown automatically. It is shown after I click on MyLocationButton on top right side. So how to incorporate the above mentioned functionality in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a class in your project and copy this code

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;



 public class AppLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {
protected LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;
private static final long min_distance_forupdate = 10;
private static final long min_time_to_update = 2 * 60 * 1000;

public AppLocationService(Context context) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


}

public Location getLocation(String provider) {
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {

try {

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, min_time_to_update, min_distance_forupdate, this);
if (locationManager != null) {
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    return location;

}
 }catch (SecurityException r){

  Log.d("loc",r.getMessage());
 }
            return location;




    }

return location;
 }

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
}
```

then in your maps activity in onMapReady function use this code

```
    mMap = googleMap;
    appLocationService = new AppLocationService(MapsActivity.this);


    Location newlocation =     appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (newlocation != null) {
        double curlat = newlocation.getLatitude();
        double curlog = newlocation.getLongitude();

        Log.d("latitude", curlat + "  ----" + curlog);



        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(curlat, curlog);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Your   location"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(curlat, curlog);
        CameraUpdate yourLocation =    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 5);
        mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()

                .target(new LatLng(curlat, curlog))      // Sets the center of the map to location user

                .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: thanx a lot friend

Comment: if there comes any issue do ask me otherwise mark my answer

Comment: mark the answer plz